# Compiling AOSP and running Android Studio on the same machine, a possible scenario?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source, java

I'm trying to get my Fedora 22 machine to be able to both compile AOSP, which requires OpenJDK 1.7, and run Android Studio, which requires OpenJDK 1.8 (for Gradle).

Is there a way to make them both work correctly and live happily together on the same OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many JDK versions (OpenJDK, Oracle, 6, 7, 8) installed as you want.

The `make` process for the AOSP project will probably pick up the version form the `JAVA_HOME` variable (perhaps you can even supply one yourself?).

In Android Studio you can select the JDK per module with right click on module -> open module settings -> SDK location.

I haven't tried it myself but I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work.